# Badge achievement message missing

Tags: bug, badges

Yesterday I had earned two badges on different SE communities each and normally I would get messages in achievements, but it didn't happen this time for any of the badges. So I'm wondering if this could be some kind of bug?

Comment: I've been noticing this for months, but the badge always turns up. What browser are you using on which opsys? I'm on Brave 64, Win 10, up to date.

Comment: @W.O. Using Firefox on Win 10, but don´t think it´s a problem of browser.  Just few days ago I got a mesage when earning a badge and still geting mesages of reputation changes.

Comment: I'm getting the rep change notifications, but where the cup used to glow green, no badge notifications. Just taken the tour on three sites (musicfans, conlang and askpatents), got the badge immediately, no notification. The network profile updated right away though.

Comment: Incidentally, the hat notifications turned-up fine.

Comment: Veteran users do not get notifications for "minor" badges.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Chasing And what are such "minor" badges? How is such veteran user defined?

Comment: @convert it's all in the duplicate, written down by balpha. To sum it up, "veteran" is one with the association bonus i.e. 200 rep on at least one site, and minor badges are bronze badges that don't appear in the list posted by balpha.